# Set custom accessory type in cusom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, accessorytype

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, and I would like to add a custom accessory type to it. I can set the custom accessory type in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but I don't think that is an ideal way.

Question:
How can I set a custom accessory type to a custom cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign a custom UIView (image,button, etc..) to the property

```
cell.accessoryView = <your custom view>;
```

If the custom accessoryView is different in every cell the in the delegate method

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

you can create the assignment, if it is the same in each cell then you can subClass a UITableViewCell (follow this tutorial [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702))